# Indexes are not working in entity framework

Tags: database, oracle, entity-framework

I have using entity framework in my project(using MVC in .Net) and using Oracle as database.

Have a large data (Millions of records) in one table.
And there are indexes on many columns.

When i access data from view using above table with where clause with multiple conditions then after it execute fast. But i use same where clause from code using entity framework then it takes much time (May be 10-15 minutes).

Is there any relation of indexes to entity framework?

Indexes not supported in entity framework?

Query generated by LINQ:

```
SELECT 
CAST( "Extent1"."LOPNR1" AS number(9,0)) AS "C1", 
CAST( "Extent1"."LOPNR2" AS number(9,0)) AS "C2", 
CAST( "Extent1"."INTFTG" AS number(9,0)) AS "C3", 
"Extent1"."LON" AS "LON", 
"Extent1"."EZX" AS "EZX", 
"Extent1"."FAKTNR" AS "FAKTNR", 
 ...........................

 CAST( "Extent1"."UTBETDAT" AS number(9,0)) AS "C11", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."INBETDAT" AS number(9,0)) AS "C12", 
"Extent1"."TRANSTEXT" AS "TRANSTEXT", 
"Extent1"."ANVFRITT" AS "ANVFRITT", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."FLAGGA3" AS number(4,0)) AS "C13", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."FLAGGA4" AS number(4,0)) AS "C14", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."FLAGGA5" AS number(4,0)) AS "C15", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."DATUPPDAT" AS number(9,0)) AS "C16", 
.......... 
"Extent1"."TRI" AS "TRI", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."OBJIDNR" AS number(18,0)) AS "C17", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."DOKLOPNR" AS number(18,0)) AS "C18", 
.............................
 CAST( "Extent1"."FULLDATE" AS number(18,0)) AS "C30", 
"Extent1"."RADID" AS "RADID", 

"Extent1"."INTFTG_VIEW" AS "INTFTG_VIEW", 
 CAST( "Extent1"."ISOBJECT" AS number(18,0)) AS "C31"
FROM (SELECT 
  "ViewName"."LOPNR1" AS "LOPNR1", 
  "ViewName"."LOPNR2" AS "LOPNR2", 
  "ViewName"."INTFTG" AS "INTFTG", 
  .....................................
  "ViewName"."BOKFDAG_VIEW" AS "BOKFDAG_VIEW", 
  "ViewName"."INTFTG_VIEW" AS "INTFTG_VIEW", 
  "ViewName"."ISOBJECT" AS "ISOBJECT"
  FROM "SchemaName"."ViewName" ) "Extent1"
WHERE ((3 <> ( CAST(  CAST( "Extent1"."FLAGGA3" AS number(4,0)) AS number(9,0)))) AND                (9 <> ( CAST(  CAST( "Extent1"."FLAGGA4" AS number(4,0)) AS number(9,0)))) AND     ("Extent1"."BOKFBEL" > 0) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (1 = 1) AND (3636002 = ( CAST( "Extent1"."INTFTG" AS number(9,0)))) AND (90 = ( CAST(  CAST( "Extent1"."VTYP" AS number(4,0)) AS number(9,0))))    AND (1 = 1))
```

Comment: as Entity framework just executes SQL query, and indexes applied on DB level, then Entity Framework shouldn't care about indexes. But it might be an issue on Oracle provider for Entity Framework side. Can you post your Entity Framework code that you use to query these data? Maybe it does duplicate queries?

Comment: The LINQ query would also be helpful, if possible.

Comment: My screen is search/result type, where clause string is created dynamically and append in LINQ where clause

Comment: Try to offer the search parameters as decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can't use any indexes. Let say that you have an index on Extent1.FLAGGA3.
Oracle looks at your WHERE clause and see

```
 CAST(Extent1.FLAGGA3, ...) <> 3
```

If it would be

```
Extent1.FLAGGA3 <> 3
```

then index could be used, but when there is a function on a column, in order to use index, Oracle needs to apply that function to every key in the index. Most likely that is quite expensive and Oracle opt out of using that index.

Why do you need all that CASTs?

Looks like general solution for the CAST problem is to use contains instead of =,
cntr-V from one of the answers:

```
short[] shortValue = new short[] { 6 };
var entityList = from r in rep.DataContext.FooTable
--where r.SmallIntColumn == shortValue
where shortValue.Contains(r.SmallIntColumn)
select r;
```

Comment: Actualy CAST is done by Entity framework because in Oracle its number as number(10,0) so, in model (in code) i use Int32.

Comment: Can you ask not to do it? You comparing 2 numbers, why you need to cast one of them from number(4) to number(9)? You actually HAVE TO kill that cast. I see that this is a common problem: http://blog.hompus.nl/2013/01/21/filtering-on-a-tinyint-with-entity-framework/